# How is exception thrown from Hibernate DAO to Spring MVC controller?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Iam new to spring.How can I throw the exception from my Hibernate DAO calss to service and then to my controller and how to inform UI about the exception.Plese help me with exception throwing to indicate the user.

Service Class:

```
@Service
public class ServiceImpl  implements Service {
    private static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(AccessServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired  
    private DAO DAO;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<PrinterVO> getDetails() {

        List<VO> printerList = null;
        try {
            LOGGER.info("Inside getAllPrinters()");
            printerList = DAO.getAllPrinters();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("getAllPrinters() Error :", e);
        }

        return printerList;
    }
```

DAO:

```
public class DAOImpl implements DAO {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value="ressessionFactory")
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<VO> getDetails() {

        List<VO> printerList  = null;
        try {
            LOGGER.info("Inside getAllPrinters()");
            printerList =  sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from PrinterVO").list();
        } catch(HibernateException e) {
            LOGGER.error("getAllPrinters() Error : ", e);

        }
        return printerList;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're catching the exception, so it cannot propagate to your UI. You should only catch an exception if you have some action that you need to perform. Logging is not an action.

In your DAO, you should inject your `Session` (if you really want to depend on Hibernate) or a JPA `EntityManager`. If you are using dependency injection, you shouldn't be invoking factory methods.

I don't see anything in your code that would tell me how data gets to your UI, so I can't tell you how to pass an exception along to your UI either. Spring come with its own exception handling and translation facilities, so you shouldn't have to write many `try/catch` blocks, but rather rely on Spring's capabilities to present sensible error messages.

Comment: Do i want to remove all try blocks in DAO and service layer.I have added HibernateException and normal EXception in Service.Do u like to see my controller code?

Comment: Okay, it looks like you're using Spring MVC. There are several, confusing ways to deal with exceptions using Spring MVC, but my basic advice is still the same: don't write `try/catch` blocks. [This article](http://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc) may be helpful to you.

Comment: Can you create and show one block of exception handling in my above code[service, dao and contorller]